# FastEndpoints parameter not created in swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, fast-endpoints

[image: Simple configuration of application]
Simple configuration of application

[image: Added an endpoint with id parameter]
Added an endpoint with id parameter

[image: parameter is not showed in swagger]
parameter id is not showed in swagger

I'am working with FastEndPoints 5.23.0
What could be the issue?
I've followed the documentation (https://dev.fastendpoints-doc-site.pages.dev/docs/model-binding#from-route-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your swagger [middleware setup](https://fast-endpoints.com/docs/swagger-support#enable-swagger) is wrong.

```cs
using FastEndpoints;
using FastEndpoints.Swagger; //add this

var bld = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
bld.Services
   .AddFastEndpoints()
   .SwaggerDocument(); //define a swagger document

var app = bld.Build();
app.UseFastEndpoints()
   .UseSwaggerGen(); //add this
app.Run();
```

fastendpoints uses nswag and doesn't support swashbucke, which i believe is what you're trying with.